# Generating Slidify slides with knit to HTML on RStudio Version 0.99.467

Tags: rstudio, knitr, slidify

After writing up a Slidify content when pressing knit HTML button on RStudio IDE version 0.99.467 it only renders HTML file and NOT the slides? I have used default YAML and a YAML used by Ramnath from his github repository examples with the same result. Is there a change or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this steps fixed my issue.

```
Restart R (or alternatively restart RStudio).
install.packages('stringr')
devtools::install_github('muschellij2/slidify')
library(slidify)
slidify("index.Rmd")
```

[full discussion is found here](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/407)